# Proxy server's Load balance configuration in Websphere application server 8.5.5

Tags: proxy, server, websphere

I am trying to configure a proxy server to load balance the HTTP requests between my two application servers.

I have achieved to route the requests using round robin method.

Now that, I am wondering how to configure the enable session affinity, since I am facing issue after login, with the error - session terminate.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any further information is required.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!--HTTP server plugin config file for the cell sterlingdevCell01 generated on 2015.09.30 at 06:53:03 PM IST-->
<Config ASDisableNagle="false" AcceptAllContent="true" AppServerPortPreference="HostHeader" ChunkedResponse="false" FIPSEnable="false" FailoverToNext="false" HTTPMaxHeaders="300" IISDisableFlushFlag="false" IISDisableNagle="false" IISPluginPriority="High" IgnoreDNSFailures="false" KillWebServerStartUpOnParseErr="false" MarkBusyDown="false" OS400ConvertQueryStringToJobCCSID="false" RefreshInterval="60" ResponseChunkSize="64" SSLConsolidate="true" StrictSecurity="false" TrustedProxyEnable="false" UseInsecure="false" VHostMatchingCompat="false">
   <Log LogLevel="Error" Name="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/logs/http_plugin.log"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnable" Value="true"/>
   <Property Name="ESIMaxCacheSize" Value="1024"/>
   <Property Name="ESIInvalidationMonitor" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnableToPassCookies" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESICacheidFull" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="PostSizeLimit" Value="-1"/>
   <Property Name="PostBufferSize" Value="0"/>
   <Property Name="PluginInstallRoot" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/"/>
   <Property Name="Keyfile" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.kdb"/>
   <Property Name="Stashfile" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.sth"/>
   <VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:5060"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:5061"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9066"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9086"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9449"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9049"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9067"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9087"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9450"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9050"/>
   </VirtualHostGroup>
   <VirtualHostGroup Name="proxy_host">
      <VirtualHost Name="*:1024"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:1025"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9061"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9062"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9081"/>
   </VirtualHostGroup>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="cluster01" PostBufferSize="0" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
      <Server CloneID="19vq01jfc" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="sterlingdevNode01_member01" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9086" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9449" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <Server CloneID="19vq01lue" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="sterlingdevNode02_member02" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9087" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9450" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="sterlingdevNode01_member01"/>
         <Server Name="sterlingdevNode02_member02"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="dmgr_sterlingdevCellManager01_Cluster" PostBufferSize="0" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
      <Server ConnectTimeout="0" ExtendedHandshake="false" MaxConnections="-1" Name="sterlingdevCellManager01_dmgr" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false"/>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="sterlingdevCellManager01_dmgr"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster" PostBufferSize="0" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
      <Server CloneID="123456789" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" MaxConnections="-1" Name="sterlingdevNode01_server01" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9080" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9443" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="sterlingdevNode01_server01"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster" PostBufferSize="0" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
      <Server CloneID="987654321" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" MaxConnections="-1" Name="sterlingdevNode02_server02" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9081" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="sterlingdev.lmggi.com" Port="9444" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/etc/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="sterlingdevNode02_server02"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <UriGroup Name="proxy_host_cluster01_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/snoop/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/hello"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/hitcount"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/ibm_security_logout"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/servlet/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/sbc/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/sma/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/smcfs/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/services/YIFWebService"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/services/YIFWebService/wsdl/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/ibm_security_logout"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="cluster01" UriGroup="proxy_host_cluster01_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="proxy_host"/>
   <UriGroup Name="default_host_cluster01_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/commsvc.rest/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/ibm_security_logout"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="cluster01" UriGroup="default_host_cluster01_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
   <UriGroup Name="proxy_host_server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/Landmark_Store/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/sbc/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/sma/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/smcfs/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/services/YIFWebService"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/services/YIFWebService/wsdl/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/ibm_security_logout"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster" UriGroup="proxy_host_server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="proxy_host"/>
   <UriGroup Name="default_host_server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/commsvc.rest/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/ibm_security_logout"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster" UriGroup="default_host_server01_sterlingdevNode01_Cluster_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
   <UriGroup Name="proxy_host_server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/Landmark_Store/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/sbc/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/sma/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/smcfs/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/services/YIFWebService"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/services/YIFWebService/wsdl/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/yantrawebservices/ibm_security_logout"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster" UriGroup="proxy_host_server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="proxy_host"/>
   <UriGroup Name="default_host_server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/commsvc.rest/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsp"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsv"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/*.jsw"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/j_security_check"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBM_WS_SYS_RESPONSESERVLET/ibm_security_logout"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster" UriGroup="default_host_server02_sterlingdevNode02_Cluster_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
   <RequestMetrics armEnabled="false" loggingEnabled="false" rmEnabled="false" traceLevel="HOPS">
      <filters enable="false" type="URI">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="/snoop"/>
         <filterValues enable="false" value="/hitcount"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="SOURCE_IP">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="255.255.255.255"/>
         <filterValues enable="false" value="254.254.254.254"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="JMS">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="destination=aaa"/>
  </filters>

      <filters enable="false" type="WEB_SERVICES">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="wsdlPort=aaa:op=bbb:nameSpace=ccc"/>
      </filters>
   </RequestMetrics>
</Config>
```

Comment: @Joey (http://stackoverflow.com/users/3143365/joey): Hope you can help on this. I am looking out for sticky session on Websphere!

Comment: Just for load balancing better solution than proxy is IBM Http Server with WebSphere plugin, which will load balance among servers and also takes care about session affinity.

Comment: @trikelef Thanks for your comment. Sorry for my ignorance, are you trying to say I should add the below lines in the plugin-cfg file. I have added it for your reference. Also, if we can create the proxy balancer from admin console, please let me know the steps for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: user1455463 I assume you are referring to the Java proxy server that you can configure via WebSphere admin console. That proxy server is session aware and should route request to the correct servers. Are your servers in the same cell, configured in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The most preferred solution is to use **Websphere Plugin** for Load Balancing. There are also many products provided by IBM or other vendors that can act as Reverse Proxies/Load Balancers, like IBM ODR, IBM Websphere Proxy Server or IBM Edge Load Balancer e.t.c.

However if for some reason you are not able to use something like this you may follow the steps below using Apache 2.X and a number of Standalone Websphere Application Servers(in this case WAS1 and WAS2):

- Declare a proxy balancer like the following:

  ```
  <Proxy balancer://mylb/>
      BalancerMember http://<WAS1_hostname>:9080 route=WAS1 retry=120 status=+E
      BalancerMember http://<WAS2_hostname>:9080 route=WAS2 retry=120 status=+E
      ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
  </Proxy>
  ```
- In each WAS console go to **Application servers > server_name > Web container > Custom properties**, set the following properties,then restart the server:

> HttpSessionCloneId = WAS1 (i.e. equal to **route** value above)
>
> CloneSeparator = **.**

- Then use the balancer per your preference, for example:

  ```
  <Location />
          ProxyPass balancer://mylb/mycontextpath/
          ProxyPassReverse balancer://mylb/mycontextpath/
          ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /mycontextpath /
  </Location>
  ```

This is not an officially supported solution (you just need apache http server with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_balancer) but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: This information unfortunately is incorrect. WebSphere plugin is one of the supported method, I find it the best, but there are also others. Like you can use Proxy server provided in WAS, you can use ODR, or you can even use third party balancer like F5. I dont know where you found info that it is only supported way...

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the answer to include your comments. As for the method I mention it is not clearly documented anywhere (and not officially supported as you say) but it is tested and works.